# i am trying to link my student list with there profile page

Tags: php

i want to link each student name from student list with there profile page i have tried but its not working can any one solve this.Thanks in advance.

This is student list code and i am sending data to delete page for deleting any student from list and also i want link there names with there profiles if i want to check there profile.

```
    <form action="php\student_list_delete.php" method="POST">
<table  id="table_style"  border="1px"  align="center">

        <tr>
        <td colspan="6" style="border-right: none;  border-bottom: none;">
        <h2>Student Information List</h2><b>Dempartment of Computer Sceince</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-left: none; border-bottom: none;"><img src="images/logo.png" width="80px" height="80px"></td>
        </tr>


<!-- ============= Student Information List header Start here  ============= -->    
            <?php 

                std_list_header();

                ?>


<!-- ================= Student Information List header End here ================ -->    



        <tr class="table_header" >
        <th width="50px">S/N</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>F/Name</th>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th>Semister</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>



<!-- ================= Student Information List body Start here ================ -->

<?php

    $query="SELECT id,name,fname,phone FROM  student"; 
$resultset=$connection->query($query); 

$count=0; 
while($r=$resultset->fetch_assoc()){
    $count++; 
echo "<tr><td>".$count."</td><td><a href='".$r["id"]."'>".$r["name"]."</a></td><td>".$r["fname"]."</td><td></td><td><td>".$r["phone"]."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='chb".$count."' value='".$r["id"]."'></td></tr>
"; 

}
?>

<!-- ================= Student Information List body End here ================ -->


        <tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
        </tr>

</table >
</form>
```

This is the student profile page code.

```
function std_table_profile(){

$result=$connection->query("SELECT name,fname,gender,email,phone,address,image FROM student WHERE id='".$r["id"]."'");

$rs=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: left join? `select * from student left join student_profile on studet_profile.id = student.id`

Comment: but i have fetch data from same table

Comment: in which file should id apply this query

Comment: If its the same tabel why dont you just fetch all data? Or are you trying to fetch them by id in other place?

Comment: Ok i got it, how do you pass the id of the student to the profile page? Get or post? Depending on which method you are using you can &_get[id] or &_post[id], show me the link of the profile page. are you using router?

Comment: i have added the code .Thanks in advance for solving

Answer (score 0):

".$res["name"]." to ".$r["name"]."

Answer (score 0):

lets say your link to the profile page looks like this

`/profile.php?id=32`

in your profile page(profile.php) you retrieve id using `$_GET`

```
<?php

  function std_table_profile($student_id){ 
     // your query...WHERE id='".$student_id."'"...
     return $result;
  }
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $student_data = std_table_profile($id);
  print_r($student_data);
```

If you are using router you need to preg_match your uri